# How to Renew Token/Activation Link for a Delta Share Recipient?

Tags: databricks, delta-sharing

Seems like the old token expired. Is there a way to renew without deleting the recipient?

Comment: Is it standalone Delta Sharing or provided by Databricks? If later, is it Databricks to Databricks delta sharing or to external person?